# Retrieving values of non input fields with Flask

Tags: python, html, flask

Probably a stupid question, but I can't work out how to retrieve the values of anything other than input fields using python with Flask. For example, I have an html form with a  element:

```
<form action="/newgame" method="POST"> 
<input type="text" name="white">
<select>
  <option name="result" value="onezero">1-0</option>
  <option name="result" value="zeroone">0-1</option>
  <option name="result" value="draw">draw</option>
</select>
<input type="text" name="black">
<input type="submit" value="submit">
</form>
```

On serverside, if I call `print request.form.items(True)`, then I can retrieve the values from the two `<input type="text">` elements, but not from the `<select>` element.

I had a similar issue where I wanted to have a form with two submit buttons and then work out on the serverside which button had been used to submit the form. I had no luck with this either.

Help and advice appreciated.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your `name` attribute needs to be on the `select` element, not the `option` elements.  Like so:

```
<select name="result">
    <option value="onezero">1-01</option>
    ...
</select>
```